# Bundle.js isn't found when deployed to gh-pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, github-pages

I used `react-create-app` for building my application and deployed it to github-pages while strictly following the instructions I was given during the process. When I load the page I get an error in the console: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404" (Bundle.js). The app runs fine when I run it using "npm run start" locally, finding all paths, but something shady is going on on github-pages. Can somebody help me fix this issue?

Comment: Well, does the file `Bundle.js` exist in your GitHub repository?

Comment: github-pages only hosts static websites, so your node website won't work there.

Comment: It doesn't exist in my repo. It doesn't even exist locally as well, but I'm able to run the app. It's some react-create-app magic for me. Given it magically works on my computer without bundle.js I assume that it should work on github without this file being present in my repo. And react-create-app has an option to deploy a react-app to github pages, so it's supposed to work.

Comment: I mean, bundle.js exists locally, but it doesn't have the path that is specified in my index.html file by default.

Answer (score 2):

This is the [official documentation on how to deploy your React app to Github Pages](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#github-pages-https-pagesgithubcom). You need to do the following:

1. In `package.json` set `homepage` to

   {
       "homepage": "https://myusername.github.io/my-app",
   }
2. Install `gh-pages`

   yarn add gh-pages
3. Add `deploy` and `predeploy` run scripts to package.json

   "scripts": {
       "predeploy": "npm run build",
       "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
4. Deploy it

   yarn run deploy

The `gh-pages` branch will be automatically created, and the generated files pushed to this branch.

### Relative path for "homepage"

I had `404: Not Found` errors for the generated Javascript and CSS files, and it was only solved when I set the `homepage` (in package.json) value to

```
  "homepage" : "."
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to set the "homepage" variable in your package.json

and this would be your npm script command in package.json

```
"homepage": "https://<username>.github.io/<repo_name>/"
....
"scripts": {
    ...
    "deploy": "npm run build&&gh-pages -d build"
    ...
 }
```

More here in the docs : https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#building-for-relative-paths